# The same .htaccess file used on two servers to append Google Analytics?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, google-analytics

I use something like this to dynamically append Google Analytics to all pages on my website.

```
Options +Includes
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html

# These values are used for local testing...
#php_value auto_prepend_file D:/wamp/www/_prepend.php
#php_value auto_append_file D:/wamp/www/_append.php

# These values are used on production server...
php_value auto_prepend_file /var/vcap.local/dea/app/_prepend.php
php_value auto_append_file /var/vcap.local/dea/app/_append.php
```

I've commented out the first pair because currently I can only get things working on one server at a time. Is it possible to modify this `.htaccess` such that it will automatically work with both servers?

Comment: Do not use prepend as the javascript code will be **after** closing your html tag. Why don't you just use `echo` or `include`?

Comment: Not `echo` or `include` because I want to append to `.html` files.

Comment: Then simply put the code in those HTML files. Its only a replace. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has an option of replacing in all open files. You just need to open all files, replace `</body>` with `<script><!-- your analytics code --></script></body>`.

Comment: And now I see that you use `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html` which CAN execute php code like `echo` and `include` in yout .html files.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want add the code to the actual files. I want it done on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

auto_append_file and auto_prepend_file both use the include path so if the environment has the relevant directories in the include path it should be possible to do:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file _prepend.php
php_value auto_append_file _append.php
```

Comment: So one `.htaccess` that works for two servers? Could you give an example please? Where would the include path be defined, within the `.htacess`?

Comment: easiest place would be in php.ini for each environment. but htaccess works as well, but they would differ between the two hosts so you would be back to having to maintain an .htaccess file for each environment.